# Problem while returning the model from REST API only BASE class properties are present

Tags: c#, rest, inheritance, asp.net-web-api

I have 2 class

```
public class A
{
 public string a {get;set;}
 public string b {get;set;}
 public string c {get;set;}
}
```

class B is inheriting A

```
public class B:A
{
   public string x {get;set;}
}
```

My API will return

```
public async Task<B> functionName(){
     //retrieve data from DB and mapping it to B Class
}
```

Actual Output:-

```
{
  "a":"somevalue",
  "b":"somevalue",
  "c":"somevalue"
}
```

Expected Output:-

```
{
 "a":"somevalue",
 "b":"somevalue",
 "c":"somevalue",
 "x":"somevalue"
}
```

I am missing property "x" from child Class B. And all the properties from Parent Class A is present.

Comment: Show the mapping code. If the property is present it should show. Chances are you are not passing what you thing you are passing. Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or additional details to highlight ***exactly*** what was done, it will be difficult to reproduce the problem that would allow a better understanding of what is the ***actual*** problem.

Comment: Could you provide this part of the code: `//retrieve data from DB and mapping it to B Class`? Also, are you sure that `x` is not null?

Comment: @Nkosi Mapping is proper and I am getting the value for "x" while debugging. But in Postman I am not getting the data i.e, "x".